# Push a returned object into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, dom, multidimensional-array, nodelist

I'm trying to save the output of function `setData` (an object) to an array (`state=[]`), but can't figure out how. Here's the code:

```
const sbmt = document.getElementById("myForm");
const elName = document.getElementById("iname");
const elGender = document.getElementById("igender");
const elAge = document.getElementById("iage");
const elForm = document.getElementById("myForm");

const setData = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let nodeList = document.forms[0].elements;
    let flatNodeList = [...nodeList].map(x => x.value).filter(x => x !== "Submit");

    let objData = {
        userName: flatNodeList[0],
        userGender: flatNodeList[1],
        userAge: flatNodeList[2]
    };

    console.log(objData);

    return objData;
};

let state =[];

const resetForm = () => elForm.reset();

sbmt.addEventListener("submit", setData);
sbmt.addEventListener("submit", resetForm);
```

Comment: Change `return objData` to `state.push(objData)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just need to push the data into your `state` array.  Returning the object will have no affect.

```js
let state =[];

const setData = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let nodeList = document.forms[0].elements;
    let flatNodeList = [...nodeList].map(x => x.value).filter(x => x !== "Submit");

    let objData = {
        userName: flatNodeList[0],
        userGender: flatNodeList[1],
        userAge: flatNodeList[2]
    };

    console.log(objData);

    state.push(objData);
};
```